# "Stream Closed" Error caused apparently by multiple submits

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat7

I am accessing an Oracle 9 database using Java, in a Tomcat 7 environment.

In **context.xml** I have

```
<Resource type="javax.sql.DataSource" auth="Container"
    name="jdbc/myDB"
    factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
    driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
    url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:db" maxwait="10000" 
     username="temp" password="temp" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10"/>
```

My java code works most of the time, but sometimes randomly I get the **Stream Closed** exception. I suspect this may be if the user presses the buttons in the application too fast, thus starting one query before finishing another query.

This exception is caused by the doEndTag function in the following code.

```
public class SQLIteratorTag extends BodyTagSupport
{
public SQLIteratorTag()
{
    query = "";
    rs = null;
    stmt = null;
    rsmd = null;
    dbConn = null;
    con = null;
}

public int doStartTag()
    throws JspTagException
{
    String fieldName = "";
    try
    {
        DBConnection d=DBConnection.getInstance();

        con = d.getConnection();
       ...

public int doAfterBody()
    throws JspException
{
    try
    {
    ....    


public int doEndTag()
    throws JspException
{
    try
    {
        if(bodyContent != null)
        {
            bodyContent.writeOut(bodyContent.getEnclosingWriter());
        }
    }
    catch(IOException ex)
    {
        Log.getIns
```

I do not want to post too much code, but I may have posted too little.  I have no idea where the problem may lie, but I will update the question if necessary.

The exception itself is:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/charm] threw  exception [javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Stream    closed] with root cause
javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Stream closed
at c.tags.sql.SQLIteratorTag.doEndTag(SQLIteratorTag.java:218)
at   org.apache.jsp.comp_005fpara_jsp._jspService(comp_005fpara_jsp.java:708)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at com.jspbook.GZIPFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: What's the actual exception - can you post the stack trace? Are you sure it's coming from the DB side, not an interrupted connection between the server and the browser - which might match the clicking-twice scenario?

Comment: Hi Alex. I added the stack trace as requested. I am not sure where the error is coming from!

Answer (score 2):

From the stack trace, this doesn't appear to be anything to do with the database connection, but does look related to the user submitting two requests from the back end. I've changed the tags, but you might want to rephrase the question a bit and change the title to get more attention.

Essentially your application receives two requests, and processes them both. It's a while since I've seen this but as far as I can remember the first one gets this error because the browser has closed the TCP/IP connection in order to open a new one for the second request. (That's probably a bit simplistic with HTTP/1.1 as it reuses connections).

I think we worked around this by hiding a unique identifier on the page as it was generated, and then detecting if we got a second POST request on the same session with that UID - indicating they'd submitted twice. It was a while ago though so I'm rather hazy on exactly what we did, and how we stopped it being visible to the user; I do recall that we wrapped the HttpServletRequest for the second request in a HttpServletRequestWrapper that appeared to change the request from a POST to a GET, but I'd have to do some digging to figure what was going on.

**Edit:** [This link](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t54948.html) is quite old but seems to have a better way to deal with it than anything ancient I can drag up (which seems to be essentially option 2 in that post). There are probably several common ways to deal with this.

Comment: Thank you Alex.  I have updated the title as you suggest. However I might add that the java code worked fine using OC4J Application Server. This problem has only happened since I moved it to Tomcat. So my thoughts were that maybe I was setting up the database connection wrongly (which is why I posted the extract from context.xml) so that it didn't deal with the simultaneous connections in the correct manner.

Comment: @gordon613 - maybe OC4J was doing some kind of filtering already that hid the problem? Pure speculation of course. Since it's not apparently DB-related I've far exceeded my usefulness here. Good luck!